# Using Hidden Markov Models for Classification

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model

When we use HMM for classification, we need to train one HMM per class. My question is: How to find the matrices A,B,\pi?? What is the meaning of them?

To clarify: A =[aij] transition matrix, aij probability for moving from state I to state j When I have just one state as I denote above how would I calculate them out?

Comment: Why do you think you need to train one HMM per state?  HMMs, by construction, deal with multiple possible states simultaneously...

Comment: I read this step in this Question <br/> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91290/how-do-i-train-hmms-for-classification<br/>